# Flex/Flash project analyzing tool wanted

Tags: apache-flex, flash, code-analysis, analysis

I am looling for tool that can eat my Adobe Flex source code (written in Adobe Flex Builder 3.0.2, Eclipse plugin) or built SWF and produce call graph, class inheritance diagram and so on. Purpose - I've got a project with actually no time to dig in complicated calculations performed there (it's an interactive Flash game with heavy keyboard usage and lots of physics). Can you give me a piece of advice? Thank you.

Comment: Probably not quite what you're looking for, but FlexPMD is the closest thing I know of.

Comment: Oh, it's a very nice tool, though is doesn't have key features I need. I think I'll become a fan of it soon ))

Answer (score 0):

[as said Flextras](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexpmd/FlexPMD) or standard Flash Builder Profiler/Debugger to control it on the fly.